# Access denied for non Existing user (Spring-Boot JDBC Driver)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm following a tutorial on Spring Boot and everytime i try to run the application i get the following error, the fact is that in the application.properties i pass on the right user name so i don't know where does it get that User from. I mean it's my windows user ID but i'll expect for spring boot to pick on the user i specified in the application.properties, can anybody help me understand why is this happening and how to solve this?:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Marco'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:428) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
at com.example.demo.PopsterBackend2Application.main(PopsterBackend2Application.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name_of_the_app
spring.datasourde.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

UserService.java:

```
package com.example.demo.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {
    public List<UserOfPopster> getStudents(){
    return List.of(new UserOfPopster(1L, "Marc0", "Marco1A3B", "Marco", "Meneghetti",     LocalDate.of(1996, 1, 12), "marcom962015@gmail.com"));
}
}
```

UserController.java:

```
package com.example.demo.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/user")
 public class UserController {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}


@GetMapping
public List<UserOfPopster> getStudents(){
    return userService.getStudents();
}
}
```

User.java (actually it's called differently):

```
package com.example.demo.User;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table
public class UserOfPopster {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="userOfPopster_sequence", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName =    "userOfPopster_sequence")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="userOfPopster_sequence")
private Long user_id;
private String user_name;
private String password;
private String name;
private String surname;
private LocalDate Birth;
private String eMail;

public UserOfPopster(Long user_id, String user_name, String password, String name, String surname, LocalDate birth, String eMail) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.user_name = user_name;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    Birth = birth;
    this.eMail = eMail;
}

public UserOfPopster() {
}

public UserOfPopster(String user_name, String password, String name, String surname, LocalDate birth, String eMail) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    Birth = birth;
    this.eMail = eMail;
}

public Long getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public LocalDate getBirth() {
    return Birth;
}

public void setBirth(LocalDate birth) {
    Birth = birth;
}

public String geteMail() {
    return eMail;
}

public void seteMail(String eMail) {
    this.eMail = eMail;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof UserOfPopster userOfPopster)) return false;
    return Objects.equals(getUser_id(), userOfPopster.getUser_id()) && Objects.equals(getUser_name(), userOfPopster.getUser_name()) && Objects.equals(getPassword(), userOfPopster.getPassword()) && Objects.equals(getName(), userOfPopster.getName()) && Objects.equals(getSurname(), userOfPopster.getSurname()) && Objects.equals(getBirth(), userOfPopster.getBirth()) && Objects.equals(geteMail(), userOfPopster.geteMail());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getUser_id(), getUser_name(), getPassword(), getName(), getSurname(), getBirth(), geteMail());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "user_id=" + user_id +
            ", user_name='" + user_name + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
            ", Birth=" + Birth +
            ", eMail='" + eMail + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Popster_Backend_2</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thank you all to whoever is gonna help me :)

Comment: Did you install a MariaDB database locally?

Comment: Nono, i use mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have a typo in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.username=root
```

instead of

```
spring.datasourde.username=root
```